# unable to read files from /sdcard/Download in Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

My project uses android NDK and there's a C++ file which needs to read /sdcard/Download/blah.nx to initialize.

C++ code looks like:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<file>> files;
std::string filePath = std::string(getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE")) + "/Download/";
bool exists(std::string name)
{
    std::string test = filePath + name;
    FILE* file = fopen(test.c_str(), "rb");
    if (file != nullptr) {
        fclose(file);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE has already been added in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

When debugging, file pointer is always null, what could be the reason ?

Comment: That that file was not created by your app. On Android 11+ devices an app can only read its own files. And media files of other apps. Give it a .jpg extension. Tell Android version of used device.